# jquery marquee make scroller from top to bottom instead of right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make my marquee scroll from top to bottom, instead of on right to left.

I fount a snippet online that uses jquery .animate but I can figure out how to make it scroll instead on move right to left

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var marquee = function() {
    var window_width = window.innerWidth;
    var speed = 12 * window_width;
    $('#marquee li:first').animate( {left: '-980px'}, speed, 'linear', function() {
      $(this).detach().appendTo('#marquee ul').css('', "100%");
      marquee();
    });
  };
  if ($("#marquee li").length > 1) {
    marquee();
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#marquee {
  background: #090;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 1035px;
}

#marquee ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#marquee li {
  width: 980px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marquee">
 <ul>  
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust for it to work on Y not X, so switch out width for height, and you'll need to position fixed or absolute, so it spans the entire window height.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var marquee = function() {
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;
    var speed = 12 * window_height;
    $('#marquee li:first').animate( {top: '100%'}, speed, 'linear', function() {
      $(this).detach().appendTo('#marquee ul').css('', "100%");
      marquee();
    });
  };
  marquee();
});
```

---

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#marquee {
  background: #090;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

#marquee ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

#marquee li {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  font-size:14px;

}
```

Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/7sunt6fz/1/

Comment: This works but only for 1 item, once I add more items it doesnt work.